# CakePHP Authenticate with LDAP

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, ldap, cakephp-2.0

I have extended BaseAuthorise in CakePHP and created a new class named LdapAuthenticate, this is located within my /app/Controller/Component/Auth/LdapAuthenticate and it currently looks like this

```
<?php

App::uses('BaseAuthorize', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class LdapAuthenticate extends BaseAuthorize {
    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response) {
        // Do things for ldap here.

        echo "Running...";

    }
}
```

Within my AppControl I have

```
public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'),
            'authenticate' => array('Ldap')
        )
    );
```

And then within my login method I have

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Auth->authorize();

    }
}
```

However I am getting the error

```
Error: Class LdapAuthenticate contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (BaseAuthorize::authorize)
```

However in the CakePHP documentation and cookbook it instructs me to set it up the way I have LdapAuthetnticate extends BaseAuthorise with a function for authenticate which can return an object of false depending on if the user logged in or not.

Can anybody suggest why this error is being produced?

Comment: You've mixed up [authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authorize-objects) and [authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-authentication-objects).

Comment: Neither work without one another.

Answer (score 0):

You've extended an abstract class - so you must provide your own implementation of the abstract method - in this case you must implement:

```
authorize ( array $user , CakeRequest $request )
```

Answer (score 0):

as ndm says you are extending `BaseAuthorize` but what you want is `BaseAuthenticate`

```
class LdapAuthenticate extends BaseAuthenticate
{

    public function authenticate(CakeRequest $request, CakeResponse $response)
    {
        // ....
        return $userData;
    }
```